# how to keep the client safe when navigating to another component using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete

I have 2 different component that navigate in each other. Like in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-ypoupd?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html)

1. I create a invoice, choose client name, invoice_name and description, and in the end click Add Product.
2. I add product, and navigate in invoice component. When I navigate in invoice, client name is deleted.

For other data in invoice component I solution, but, for client I have a problem.

Create a data service like code below:

```
export class DataService {
  _data = new Map<string, any>();

  setData(key, value) {
    this._data.set(key, value);
  }

  getData(key) {
    return this._data.get(key);
  }

  clear() {
    this._data = new Map<string, any>();
  }
}
```

And in InvoiceComponent write this code:

```
export class AutocompleteDisplayExample implements OnInit {
  clientid: number;
    selectedClient: User;
  addsale: FormGroup;
  products: Array<Products> = [];
  myControl = new FormControl();
   id_client: FormControl = new FormControl();
  options: User[] = [
    { id_client: '1', name: 'Mary', phone: '654987' },
    { id_client: '2', name: 'Shelley', phone: '123456' },
    { id_client: '3', name: 'Igor', phone: '00365987' }
  ];
  filteredOptions: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(
    public service: Service,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private dService: DataService
  ) {
    let invoice = '';
    if (this.dService.getData('invoice')) {
      invoice = this.dService.getData('invoice');
    }
    let description = '';
    if (this.dService.getData('description')) {
      description = this.dService.getData('description');
    }
    let id_client = '';
    if (this.dService.getData('id_client')) {
      id_client = this.dService.getData('id_client');
    }

    this.addsale = this.fb.group({
      'invoice_number': new FormControl(invoice, Validators.required),
      'description': new FormControl(description, Validators.required),
      'id_client': new FormControl(id_client, Validators.required)
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.id_client.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
    this.allproducts();
    this.service.productList.subscribe(productList => {
      this.products = productList;
      this.addsale.controls.Subtotal.setValue(this.subtotal)
    });
  }

  get subtotal() {
    return this.products
      .map(p => p.price * p.quantity)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
  allproducts() {
    this.products = this.service.getProduct();
  }

  displayFn(user?: User): string | undefined {
    return user ? user.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name: string): User[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }


  updateClient(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {
    if (ev.isUserInput) {
      if (componentid === 'id_client') {
        this.clientid = idd;
        console.log('idd', idd)
        this.addsale['controls']['id_client'].setValue(ev.source.value);
      } else {
        console.log('ooops');
      }
    }
  }
  saveData() {
    this.dService.setData('invoice', this.addsale.get('invoice_number').value);
    this.dService.setData('description', this.addsale.get('description').value);
    this.dService.setData('id_client', this.addsale.get('id_client').value);

  }
  navigate() {
    this.saveData();
    this.router.navigate(['/prod']);
  }

}
```

Only client doesn't show , all data show correctly.

For client_id I write this code:

Html code:

```
    <form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()" class="col s12">
    <h4 style="text-align:center">add sale</h4>
    <div class="contant">
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Client Data</legend>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input formControlName="id_client" id="id_client" matInput placeholder="Select Client*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="id_client">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateClient($event, option.id_client, 'id_client')" *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
       invoice_number:
        <input formControlName="invoice_number" id="invoice_number" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s4">
       description:
        <input formControlName="description" id="description" type="text" class="validate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>    
  <button type="submit">
      Register sale
    </button>
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
```

Any idea please?  I have to keep all the invoice values, like invoice_name and description. Thank you!

Thank you

**IMAGE ILLUSTRATION:**

STEP 1:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYSpG.jpg)
STEP 2:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb4kb.jpg)
STEP 3:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIrPE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the attribute name in client Object to get the client name

You need to change in your ts file

```
 'id_client': new FormControl(id_client.name, Validators.required)
```

and In HTML

```
        <input formControlName="id_client" id="id_client" matInput placeholder="Select Client*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="id_client.name">
```

Working demo 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-jo8bub?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I put  `'id_client': new FormControl(id_client.name, Validators.required)` in my code show `error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.` In fact my name is string

Comment: have you tested yet my solution ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-jo8bub?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts . is thats what you looking for ?

Comment: Yes, in this show error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.` and not function

Comment: Where exactly because it's doesn't appear in my side

Comment: I do not understand you. Can you implement something in my demo please?

Comment: Have you any idea please? Thank you!

Comment: Honestly , I didn't understand exactly what you're looking for , in my demo i implement some change in your demo and i can't the error that's you tell me , so i suggest to edit your question with that error and code

Comment: Can you see image illustration in my post please?

Comment: Can you post your demo please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-jo8bub?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts

Comment: This isn't best solution, show error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.`